# How to rotate two rectangle widgets independently on single screen in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am learning programming in python and working on one simple gaming application in which I need to rotate two rectangles on click on them on single screen but what's happening is when I am clicking on one of them both the rectangles rotate along the origin of that rectangle that is being clicked but this is not the case with another rectangle, in fact its position is not also that that is supposed to be and when clicking on the assigned position(where that rectangle is not present) it gets rotated without rotating both the rectangles. I just need to rotate both the rectangles on clicking independently. 
    It is difficult to explain it so please try to execute the code and find whats happening.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Rotate, Rectangle, Ellipse, Color
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, CardTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string('''

<Stage_2>:
    object2: Object2
    object3: Object3

    Object2:
        id: Object2
        center: self.rotate_origin

    Object3:
        id: Object3
        center: self.rotate_origin

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    Screen:
        name:"P"
        FloatLayout:

            Button:
                pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.05}
                size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
                text: "Play"
                background_color: 255,0,1,1
                on_release:
                    root.transition.direction = "up"        
                    root.current = "stage2"

    Screen:
        name: 'stage2'
        Stage_2:
            id:s2

''')

class Object2(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.rect_pos_x = 500
        self.rect_pos_y = 425
        self.rect_pos = self.rect_pos_x, self.rect_pos_y
        self.rect_width = 150
        self.rect_height = 30
        self.rect_size = self.rect_width, self.rect_height
        self.rotate_origin_x = self.rect_pos_x + self.rect_width / 2
        self.rotate_origin_y = self.rect_pos_y + self.rect_height / 2
        self.rotate_origin = self.rotate_origin_x, self.rotate_origin_y
        self.angle = 135
        print('rect 1')
        with self.canvas:
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0,197,68))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)

    def rotate(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.angle += 90
        if (self.angle > 315):
            self.angle = 225
        with self.canvas:
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.rotate()
            print(self.angle)
class Object3(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.rect_pos_x = 500
        self.rect_pos_y = 250
        self.rect_pos = self.rect_pos_x, self.rect_pos_y
        self.rect_width = 150
        self.rect_height = 30
        self.rect_size = self.rect_width, self.rect_height
        self.rotate_origin_x = self.rect_pos_x + self.rect_width / 2
        self.rotate_origin_y = self.rect_pos_y + self.rect_height / 2
        self.rotate_origin = self.rotate_origin_x, self.rotate_origin_y
        self.angle = 135
        print('rect 2')
        with self.canvas:
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(1,255,0))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)

    def rotate(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.angle += 90
        if (self.angle > 315):
            self.angle = 225
        with self.canvas:
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.rotate()
            print(self.angle)

class Stage_2(Widget):
    object2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    object3 = ObjectProperty(None)

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = Manager()

class ScreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreensApp().run()
```

Comment: Your `on_touch_up()` method is using `collide_point()` which compares the touch point to the `Widget` `pos` and `size`, not the `Rectangle`.

Comment: Thanks for helping @JohnAnderson but this is not probably whats the problem is all about, even before clicking on the rectangle the position of the second rectangle is not what it is supposed to be...please run the code once if you can to see whats the output is because it is really difficult to discuss the problem...but as far as problem is concerned I think it is somewhere related to canvas ... thankful of you...please help me out!

Comment: I have run your code and I am confident about the problem being your use of `collide_point`. Also. you should put `PushMatrix()` at the start of your `Canvas` instructions and `PopMatrix()` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include `PushMatrix()` and `PopMatrix()` in your `canvas` instructions, then only the current `Widget` will be affected. And then, if you adjust the `Widget` `size` and `pos` to that of the `Rectangle`, you should get better (but not perfect) `collide_point` performance:

```
    with self.canvas:
        PushMatrix()
        Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
        Color(rgb=(1,255,0))
        Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
        PopMatrix()
        self.pos = self.rect_pos
        self.size = self.rect_size
```

This needs to be done whenever you use `with self.canvas` that involves `Rotation`, `Scale`, or `Translate`. The `collide_point()` will still be looking at the `Widget` `size` and `pos`, not the `Rectangle`, but at least the centers of the `Widget` and its `Rectangle` should coincide.

Comment: Brilliant!...Thank you very much @JohnAnderson ...You just did it! I am really thankful for you ...keep it up helping like this!